# SQL Server: Return earliest datetime value for distinct value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

```
SELECT 
   o.Office, c.Manager, MIN(c.Dateapproved)
FROM 
   dbo.Customers AS c 
JOIN 
   dbo.OfficeNumbers AS o ON (c.SiteID = o.SiteID)
WHERE 
   IsApproved = 1
GROUP BY 
   Manager, Office, Dateapproved
ORDER BY 
   O.Office, c.Manager, MIN(c.Dateapproved)
```

Every time a manager approves a customer a new customer is added to the table along with the associated manager and the date of approval.

With the above query I return every approval from my customers table.

I am trying to get the earliest customers `DateApproved` for each manager. There are 12 managers in my table and I only want back 12 rows.

I have tried placing a distinct clause within the select statement next to `c.client` however, this is throwing the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `DateApproved` from the `group by`:

```
Select  o.Office, c.Manager, min(c.Dateapproved)
FROM dbo.Customers c JOIN 
     dbo.OfficeNumbers AS o
     ON (c.SiteID= o.SiteID)
WHERE IsApproved=1
Group By Manager, Office
Order By O.Office, c.Manager;
```

It isn't needed in the `order by` either, because the office and manager uniquely identifies each row.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`, for example with a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    Select  o.Office, c.Manager, c.Dateapproved,
            rn = Row_Number () OVER ( Partition By Manager, Office
                                      Order By Dateapproved ASC )
    FROM dbo.Customers AS c JOIN dbo.OfficeNumbers AS o
        ON (c.SiteID= o.SiteID)
    WHERE IsApproved=1
)
SELECT Office, Manager, Dateapproved
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
Order By Office, Manager, Dateapproved
```

Comment: *shrug* it says you made it so - did you edit it more than 10 times in the grace period? Did you check the community wiki box by mistake?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: i haven't edited it, if the edit-history has a chronological order i've even made it   CW before i've saved it which is odd.

Comment: @AaronBertrand; It's not that important. I think i've clicked something accidentally. Even though i don't understand why there is no "unwiki"-button ;)